# Dynamically loading jQuery when it's not available or version isn't high enough

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing a script for others to use on their websites. I'd like to use jQuery in this script. Because I don't have control over what frameworks people use on their sites, I need to make sure jQuery is available and that it's version 1.8 or higher. Here's my take on it. Does anyone see anything I could/should be doing differently? Is there a better way of doing this?

```
//start anon function for whole script
;(function(){
    var $,
        hasOwn = ({}).hasOwnProperty,
        //get ie version returns false if ie>=11 or not ie
        ieVersion = function(){
            var v = 3,
                div = document.createElement('div'),
                all = div.getElementsByTagName('i');
            while(div.innerHTML = '<!--[if gt IE '+(++v)+']><i></i><![endif]-->', all[0]);
            return (v > 4 ? v : ('documentMode' in document ? document.documentMode : false));
        }(),
        //get which version of jQuery is currently added to the site
        jqVersion = function(){
            return 'jQuery' in window && !!window.jQuery ? parseFloat(window.jQuery.fn.jquery) : false;
        },
        //set the correct jquery version to use based on which version of ie is in use. Use an array in the case of one or more being down
        jqSrc = (!!ieVersion && ieVersion > 4 && ieVersion < 9) ? ['//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js', '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js', '//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js'] : ['//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js', '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js', '//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.0.min.js'],
        //check jquery version and if it is above 1.8 use it, if not then get own version
        jqCheck = function(first){
            var version = jqVersion();
            if(!version || version < 1.8){
                getScript(jqSrc.shift(), jqCheck);
            }else{
                if(!!first){
                    $ = window.jQuery;
                }else{
                    $ = window.jQuery.noConflict(true);
                }
                load();
            }
        },
        //function to loop and load jquery script
        getScript = function(url, callback){
            var script = document.createElement('script'),
                tag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0],
                done = false;
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.async = !0;
            script.src = url;

            script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = script.onerror = function(){
                if(!done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == 'loaded' || this.readyState == 'complete')){
                    done = true;
                    if(typeof(callback) === 'function'){
                        callback.call(this);
                    }
                    script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = script.onerror = null;
                }
            };

            tag.parentNode.insertBefore(script, tag);
        },
        load = function(){
            //Start script
            window.myGlobalFunction = new function(){
                var privateVar = 'private',
                    privateFunc = function(){
                        return true;
                    };

                this.publicVar = 'public';

                this.publicFunc = function(){
                    return true;
                };
            };
        };

    //make sure json is avaiable, if not add it
    if(!hasOwn.call(window, 'JSON') || !hasOwn.call(JSON, 'parse') || (typeof(JSON.parse) !== 'function')){
        getScript('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json3/3.3.1/json3.min.js', function(){
            //all functions are built start by checking for jQuery and it's builder
            jqCheck(true);
        });
    }else{
        //all functions are built start by checking for jQuery and it's builder
        jqCheck(true);
    }
})();
```

Comment: I'd rather parse `navigator.userAgent` to detect if a browser is IE, what you are doing feels quite hacky and is probably inefficient. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916900/detect-version-of-browser

Comment: @Cu3PO42 thank you for the input. User agents can very easily be manipulated, because of this I would much rather rely on something *more* concrete. Base on the link you provided's top answer & my current version(derived from [here](https://gist.github.com/padolsey/527683)) my current version is only 15% slower after [thousands of operations](http://jsperf.com/ie-version) which is something i'm very much okay with to stay away from user agents.

Answer (score 1):

Before actually diving into creating a jQuery checker (nice idea by the way), you might really want to check some cases before building the code. There are several issues with your script here:

- Your script assumes that there is jQuery. What if there's no jQuery at all? How would your script work? I suggest you stick to vanilla JS instead.
- Documentation too long, didn't read, developer loaded your script first. It will break. You can't detect scripts because they are parsed in order. If your script came first, it cannot see the scripts loaded after it at the point of execution.
- But what if a plugin already initialized with the version that came with the page? jQuery carries an internal cache for data, event handlers etc. If you switch jQuery now, they will break.
- Dynamically loading a script is an async operation. You can't pause it right there. JS will continue. Therefore, while your script is loading a more recent version, plugins on your page might have already initialized using the one in your page.
- Some plugins require a specific version of jQuery (like some prefer 1.4, or 1.6). Developers intentionally use them because some of these plugins use already deprecated API and weren't updated. If you load a newer version, they break.
- If you really wanted IE support, why not just load the `1.x` version rather than doing `2.x`? This removes the need to detect IE. That's why there's a `1.x` and `2.x` version in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. As for the issues: 1. Because of `'jQuery' in window && !!window.jQuery` if there isn't any jQuery at all it will be loaded. 2. This script should be loaded last. If need be I could force it with defer and/or dynamically setting the script to the bottom or start it on `window.load`. 3. Because of `$.noConflict` this shouldn't be an issue at all. 4. I don't see what you're referring to, every call to `getScript` is using a callback. Can you please elaborate? 5. As before, not a problem because of `$.noConflict` 6. I agree, I will remove `ieVersion` & the 2.0 jQuery.